# Points of bounded variation of Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, bounded-variation

May be my luck of knowledge made me ask this question. And I'm sorry for if a question is inappropriate.

I rigorously understand that Wiener process is not one of bounded variation. That is for some $\omega$-s the path of the process is not of bounded variation. But I would like to know how large is the size of the set of that $\omega$-s. More precisely $P(\omega | W_{\omega}(t) \ is \ not \ a \  function \ of \ bounded \ variation)=?$.

I can't guess whether this property holds almost everywhere.

Question has arised in finance. More exactly if the property holds almost everywhere, wouldn't that mean that making right trades (or holding right positions), we can at finite time make infinite profit. (As it seem to me, the total variation represents the maximum profit we could gain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $W$ is of bounded variation on $[0,T]$ for $\omega\in A$, where $P(A)>0$, and call it $V$. Consider partitions $\Pi_n=\{0=t_0^n<t_1^n<\ldots<t_{r_{n}}^n=T\}$ such that their mesh tends to $0$ when $n$ grows. We have $$\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^{r_{n}}|W(t_k^n)-W(t_{k-1}^n)|=V$$ on $A$. Now,$$\sum_{k=1}^{r_{n}}(W(t_k^n)-W(t_{k-1}^n))^2\leq   \left(\sup_{1\leq k\leq r_{n}}|W(t_k^n)-W(t_{k-1}^n)|\right)\sum_{k=1}^{r_{n}}|W(t_k^n)-W(t_{k-1}^n)|.$$ As $W$ is almost sure continuous and of quadratic variation on $[0,T]$, and $P(A)>0$, there must exist $\omega\in A$ such that $W(\omega)$ is continuous and of quadratic variation on $[0,T]$ (which is known to be $T$). Then, taking limits, $T\leq 0\cdot V(\omega)=0$, which is a contradiction. Thus, as you thought, $$P(\{\omega:\,W(\omega)\text{ is not of bounded variation on }[0,T]\})=1.$$

Concerning the finance part:

Usually, in a discrete time setting $\{0=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=T\}$, $$\text{money}=\sum_{j=1}^n H_j\cdot(S(t_j)-S(t_{j-1})),$$
where $\{H_j\}_{j=1}^n$ is a predictable process (mathematically, this means that $H_j$ is $\mathcal{F}_{j-1}$-measurable, where $\mathcal{F}_j=\sigma(S(t_0),\ldots,S(t_j))$, but do not worry if you do not understand this). In a real setting, $H_j$ represents your bet for time $j$, and it has to be decided at time $j-1$ based on how the price of stocks evolved until time $j-1$ (this is the idea of predictable process).

You are describing the following situation: $H_j=\text{sign}(S(t_j)-S(t_{j-1}))$. Here, $H_j$ depends on $S(t_j)$, so you have not decided your bet at time $j-1$ (your process $\{H_j\}_{j=1}^n$ is not predictable). Thus, in your situation, you decide your bet at time $j$ being based on $S(t_j)$, so obviously you will always win.

Example: Imagine a game, in which you start with $0$ money, and:

1. choose *heads* or *tails*,
2. toss a coin: if the result corresponds to what you chose, you win $1$ unit of money, otherwise you lose $1$ unit of money.
3. come back to 1.

Then your "stocks" are: $S_0=0$, $S_j=S_{j-1}+\xi_j$, where $\xi_j$ is $1$ if the $j$-th coin is heads or $-1$ if it is tails. Your bet for the $j$-th coin (the bet is decided at time $j-1$) is $H_j$, which is $1$ if you think that the $j$-th coin will be heads and $-1$ if you think it will be tails. Your final money will be $\sum_{j=1}^n H_j\xi_j$.

Comment: About the finance part. Suppose that we have some process representing price of some market security, let's take it to be stock. If you are familiar, in financial market one can take so called "short" position, which is just the oposite of the long position, case when you buy the stock. When in long position you expect the price to rise. When in short your benefit is from the falling of the price. (If describing it as a function of time), our benefit can be (if we take the right position) for one period $|S(t_{j+1})-S(t_{j})|$. So for multiple opporunities to change position we would have ...

Comment: $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|S(t_{j+1})-S(t_{j})|$. If we take the limit, (regardless of that that we can't change position so fast in real life), we would have for period of time $[0,T]$, to have benefit up to $V_{0}^{T}S(t)$. As $S(t)$, is generally taken to be of geometric brownian motion, i.e something like this $S(t)= e^{at+bW_{t}}$, so it seem to me, that we can win (in ideal situation) unlimited amount of money. It seems to me there is some contradiction is this. I mean,we shouldn't take anything which has unbounded variation, as in financial market though big but only limited money is invested.

Comment: @kolobokish I edited the answer. I added the financial part. I want to remark that I just studied some finance as an application of stochastic calculus, so if there is some nonsense just tell me and I will delete it.

Comment: What is remarkable here, is the possible maximum of my profit. Mostly we take $H_{j}$ to be adapted as you said, however in any situation we shouldn't be able to have the most profit of the market.  I understand that we don't take into account the real life constraints and so on, but anyway it seem to me, that even though the situation shouldn't be like that. I mean if we take the situation with real life constraints we wouldn't be able to use Wienner process. I think we shouldn't use it in either situation on the sole reason of having some mathematically desirable conditions.

Comment: @kolobokish As far as I know, the idea of modelling your prices as $S(t)=e^{at+bW_t}$ (for instance, the Black-Scholes model) allows the discounted prices to be martingale (the discounted prices $\hat{S}(t)$ are defined as $\hat{S}(t)=e^{-rt}S(t)$, where $r$ is the interest rate in your bank account) on a certain probability space with risk-neutral measure $P^*$, and that implies that there are no arbitrage opportunities (you cannot make a profit for certain, assuming that you "bet" at a previous time, that is, your process $H$ is predictable).

Comment: Yes, ok. Trying to be concise. I understand the mathematical background of why it is taken to be geometric brownian motion. However while using wienner process in this cases, we say something like this. "The choice you made should be adapted (or predictible process), when you don't have any insider information, and as so you won $x$ dollars, but you with probability 1 (or near 1) you could win near to infinite amount of money if you were cleverer(which is unreachable state)". So I think this can't be the situation.

Comment: @kolobokish Your choice is predictable (you decide it at a previous time, that is, your bet $H_j$ depends only until $S(t_{j-1})$) and not adapted (adapted$\neq$predictable; adapted means that you decide your bet $H_j$ after having seen $S(t_j)$). In the case of adapted, you can make your profit $\infty$, but in the case of predictable no. In basic maths, the financial market is assumed to be with no arbitrage opportunities. However, in real life it is possible that you can get richer if you know how to deal with the market.